# Google Drive marks all files as Abusive after uploading

Tags: google-drive-api

I use Google Drive API for my website (people upload their content). Now all uploading files get abused mark automatically even if the file is empty .txt blank.

Also all old files have been marked as abusive and I can't send an review because there are too many of them.

I've made a video that provides easy understanding of the problem:

https://youtu.be/xLv8zUN2t8E

Comment: I found some explanation here you can see the third answer - https://support.google.com/docs/thread/3392950?hl=en and with me this also true, when I turned off shareable link on the folder new files have stopped to be marked as abusive but this is far from solution.

Comment: This is just a hunch... are your users uploading directly to a Gdrive account from their browser? This might constitute a breach of the terms of the Drive service. Consider using a service account and write a server proxy which receives the files from the users and then forwards them to Gdrive.

Answer (score 2):

#### Answer:

*This is not something Stack Overflow can help you with. You need to contact G Suite support and talk with them directly.*

#### Further Information:

Using Google Drive to allow untrusted users to upload content, honestly, is a really bad idea. There are multiple reasons for this - the content of uploaded files isn't being vetted which can result in unwanted files in your Drive, while your G Suite quota can be used up rapidly by spam which renders your personal and site-wide upload abilities useless. You should use a dedicated file storage for this.

Contact G Suite support about this using the link relevant to you [on this page](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en&ref_topic=7067151). You can speak with a support agent and get this resolved in a private case without the need of posting any information publicly. Alternatively, you can request a review of a violation of the terms of service [here](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2463328?hl=en).

#### Request a Review Violation:

You can request a review for a violation when you go to try and share the folder. As per Google's Help Pages:

> When you try to share a file that's been flagged for a violation, you’ll see an option to have the file reviewed. To request a review of the file:
>
> - Open the file.
> - Click Share.
> - Click Request a review.

#### References:

- [Contact G Suite support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en&ref_topic=7067151)
- [Abuse program policies and enforcement](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/148505?visit_id=1-636449630948225960-1010556482&rd=1)
- [Google Terms of Service](https://policies.google.com/terms)
- [Request a review of a violation](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2463328?hl=en)

Comment: @turik97 There are alternatives out there but it's against stackoverflow's community guidelines to recommend services as it easily attracts biased opinions. You can easily find G Suite/Google Drive alternatives by [searching on the web](https://www.google.com/search?q=alternatives+to+google+drive+for+file+hosting) but be aware that most, if not all, will require some form of paid subscription. I would still [request a review of a violation](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2463328?hl=en) on your Drive folder - I've edied my answer to explain how to do that.

Comment: Thanks. I've thought about sending reviews but there are too many files literally hundreds so I don't think it is convenient in my case to do manually all of those steps.

Comment: Has the folder been marked for abuse or just the files inside?

Comment: Everything is being marked for abuse when I'm trying to share it. I've updated the question with a link to a video that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Try and share the folder itself and see if that gets flagged - if it does you can follow the above steps for requesting a review of the violation and it will be for the whole folder rather than the individual files

Comment: Folders don't have flags after sharing and can't be send for a review. I've contacted Google support and waiting for an answer.

Comment: I voted up for your answer but now I can't mark it as correct because I yet to found a solution

Comment: No worries, there's not really anything that can be done from your side, this is something Google will have to sort. I hope that you get a response from Google soon.

Answer (score 0):

To somehow download/access the file :

- Install **rclone**
- Then use the command : **rclone --drive-acknowledge-abuse** to download the file